# Toolbar components codenameone

Tags: codenameone

[image]

There are 3 components in toolbar in component inspector(image above) but if I want to get the menuButton, I cannot get it.

```
//it gives label, title
System.out.println("z " + f.getToolbar().getComponentAt(0));

//it gives button, title command
System.out.println("zz" + f.getToolbar().getComponentAt(1));

//it gives no of component = 2
System.out.println("zzz" + f.getToolbar().getComponentCount());
```

Why cant I get menuButton command of toolbar? ps I had set command behavior to side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu button isn't a command and shouldn't be manipulated directly. It has unique behavior that's abstracted on purpose. Using `getComponent(int)` is a fragile approach as it relies on specific behavior that can change suddenly and without any warning.

You need to think about the use case you are interested in and follow up thru that.

E.g.:

- If you want to control the menu icon you can do so via `sideMenuImage` & `sideMenuPressImage`
- If you want to style the menu button you can use the `MenuButton` UIID

Comment: i don't see sidemenuIMage in the theme constant(gui). Do I hav to add it manually?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be there but if it's not be sure to use my capitalization as it's case sensitive.